# OracleType.LongVarChar equivalent data type in ODP.NET

Tags: c#, oracle11g, varchar2

I am searching for `System.Data.OracleClient OracleType.LongVarChar` equivalent data type in  `ODP.NET Oracle.DataAccess.Client OracleDbType`

Example :-

`OracleType.Timestamp` is equivalent to  `OracleDbType.TimeStamp`.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracletype.aspx):

> LongVarChar - An Oracle LONG data type that contains a variable-length
>   character string with a maximum size of 2 gigabytes. Use the .NET
>   Framework String or OracleClient OracleString data type in Value.

Based on the available types in the [ODP documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b28375/OracleDbTypeEnumerationType.htm), *OracleDbType.Long* seems like it would be a match.